# Static sites for React recomendation

Tags: reactjs

I'm preparing for the development of a quite large application which will contain a lot of data fetched asynchronously, with user dashboard and more. I'm interested in creating SPA with good SEO so I'm considering few ways to do static HTML pages.

I 've tried Gatsby.js, React Snap, React Snapshot, static site generator webpack plugin

I want to avoid using Gatsby.js because of im not exactly happy with its plugin-environment. React Snap and React Snapshot seems to be a solution for smaller, less complicated projects. I've had a problem using those with larger app with async-generated content.

I know SSR would be probably the best option, but I'm not sure if I would handle that easily.

I'd like to know your opinion about this.

Comment: Have you considered next.js ?

Comment: It could be helpful. https://coffeencoding.com/cra-vs-next-js-vs-gatsby/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using Next.JS or Gatsby. From a community and support perspective, both seem to be very popular with ~250,000 downloads on npm.

Both are good for high performance SPAs, webpages etc. they both also have great SEO.

Gatsby is well suited for static sites. It is somewhat of a static site generator while Next.js is more of server side rendering out of the box. It boils down to the choice of whether you prefer just server side rendering or if you want a static site generated.

You can take a call based on how large your website/app is and how the content will be used. If the application is very large and requires frequent updates, generating all pages each time may not be worth the effort.

https://nextjs.org/ 
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't use next.js yet, but from what i've just read, it's seems pretty good solution. Did you use that? I'm wondering if next.js environment is good? And what I mean by that - Can I use react styled components and so on, or it is like with Gatsby and it have to be plugin deribelately created for this framework?